# reshape from long to wide of non-categorical values

Tags: r, reshape2, data-transform

I need to reshape date from long to wide that has non-categorical values
and not the same number of values.

An example of a dataframe:

```
df_long <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("id A",  "b",    "b",    "d",    "d","id B", "kh",   "kk",   "ip", "id C", "99", "id D", "id E"),c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1)))
```

I need this:

```
df_wide <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("id A", "b", "b", "d", "d"), c("id B", "kh", "kk", "ip", ""), c("id C", "99", "", "", ""), c("id D", "", "", "", ""), c("id E", "", "", "", "")))
```

I don't know how to reshape this since values are not categorical and not every id has the same number of values.

So I was wondering about reshaping both from long to wide and wide to long of such data.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
a = aggregate(V1~V2,transform(df_long,V2 = cumsum(grepl("id",V1))),paste,collapse=',')[,2]
read.csv(text=a,header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 id A  b  b  d  d
2 id B kh kk ip   
3 id C 99         
4 id D            
5 id E
```

since you need to transform it back, then you should do:

```
 f<-read.csv(text = with(df_long,tapply(V1,cumsum(grepl("id",V1)),paste0,collapse=",")), 
              header = FALSE, fill = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = F,na.strings = "")


 print(f,na = "")
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 id A  b  b  d  d
2 id B kh kk ip   
3 id C 99         
4 id D            
5 id E
```

Now to transform it back to your long_data, you could do:

```
with(g <- transform(stack(f),ind = c(row(f))),na.omit(g[order(ind),]))
   values ind
1    id A   1
6       b   1
11      b   1
16      d   1
21      d   1
2    id B   2
7      kh   2
12     kk   2
17     ip   2
3    id C   3
8      99   3
4    id D   4
5    id E   5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask for suggestions how to convert it back?

Comment: @Briis300 how do you want to convert it back? like how do you get the V2 from this data?

Comment: The V2 data is just a running id number for every id created (datatable:cumsum)

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df_long %>%
    separate(V1, into = c("id", "val"), fill = "left") %>%
    select(-V2) %>%
    mutate(row = cumsum(!is.na(id))) %>%
    fill(id) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    mutate(col = 1:n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = c(row, id), 
        names_from = col, 
        names_prefix = "V",
        values_from = val,
        values_fill = list(val = ""))
## A tibble: 5 x 7
#    row id    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 id    A     b     b     d     d
#2     2 id    B     kh    kk    ip    ""
#3     3 id    C     99    ""    ""    ""
#4     4 id    D     ""    ""    ""    ""
#5     5 id    E     ""    ""    ""    ""
```

PS. It seems entries from column `df_long$V2` are not used in `df_wide`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, df_long$V2 is just used as an id. 
Your solution seems to be smooth, though it spits out an error message that it cant find pivot_wider. Maybe an outdated package?

Comment: @Briis300 [`pivot_wider` is the "new" `spread`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/) (which will be deprecated) from `tidyr`; if you update to `tidyr_1.0.0` it should work.